# cannot import name 'animation' from 'matplotlib'

Tags: matplotlib, animation

I try import matplotlib with:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

But I get this error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'animation' from 'matplotlib' (C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib_*init*_.py).

I removed and reinstalled matplotlib, I tried installing older matplotlib version.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, updating `matplotlib` and restarting the kernel (in Jupyter notebook) solved the issue.
I installed this version:

> pip install --user matplotlib==3.5.0b1

I realise this question is 10 months old now.
Hope it helps other users.